# Low cardinality Dimensions in Datawarehouse

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

I've a bunch of columns in my fact tables that have a very low cardinality (~8). Each of these columns store keys that refer to a master table. I'm wondering whether to import each of these individual master tables as dimension or do I store the values directly in the fact table. Master tables have no additional attributes except the value I'm trying to store. What are the pros and cons of each approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a classic example of a **junk dimension** that combines together a number of miscellaneous, low-cardinality ﬂags and indicators (instead of putting each of them in a separate dimension table).

Disadvantages of other approaches:

- Putting every low cardinality attribute in a *separate, dedicated dimension* could result in an overly complex model with excessive number of dimension tables ([centipede fact tables](http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/centipede-fact-table/)).
- *Storing the attributes directly in the fact table* is allowed but reserved only for [degenerate dimensions](http://www.kimballgroup.com/2003/06/design-tip-46-another-look-at-degenerate-dimensions/), i.e. values like order or invoice numbers, retail point-of-sale transaction numbers - high-cardinality values that don't have any additional attributes describing them.
  Low-cardinality flags are not DDs, because even though they may consist of a sole key now, they may easily have additional attributes in the future, e.g. multiple descriptive captions for reports - short for mobile users and long for desktop users.

Details: [Design Tip #113 Creating, Using, and Maintaining Junk Dimensions](http://www.kimballgroup.com/2009/06/design-tip-113-creating-using-and-maintaining-junk-dimensions/)

Comment: Thanks Marek. I implemented it using the same idea.